# Converting format of the text in a file by using python

Tags: python, file, text

I want to convert a head file which is written in C to a class in python

Basically, the format of the head file in C (a file called `header.c` is like following:

```
#define ATTR_A          (HELLO +1L)     /*FSDSDF*/
#define ATTR_B          (HELLO +2L)     /*FSFSSF*/
```

What I want to do is writing a simple script which can read the text from `header.c` and then convert the format to a python calss and stored the result to a file called `header.py`. After conversion, it will be:

```
ATTR_A        = (HELLO +1L)
ATTR_B        = (HELLO +2L)
```

I know how to read the file and how to store the converted result into `header.py`, but I know how to do the conversion. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use `regular expressions` here. Here is a [nice tutorial](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). This is just one of the possible way to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is using `re` here.

```
>>> import re
>>> testinput = '#define ATTR_A          (HELLO +1L)     /*FSDSDF*/'
>>> r = re.split(r'#define (\w*)(\s*)(\(.*\))', testinput)
>>> print '%s = %s' %(r[1], r[3])
ATTR_A = (HELLO +1L)
```

`(\w*)` is used to extract the 'ATTR_A'

`(\s*)` is used to extract the whitespaces

Inside `(\(.*\))`, `\(` actually matches `(` and `\)` mataches `)`. `.*` matches any character except a newline.

So, after the `split`, `r= ['', 'ATTR_A', '          ', '(HELLO +1L)', '     /*FSDSDF*/']`, which a list.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module (regular expressions) to extract the parts you need from each line of text.

---

**Example:**

```
import re

input = ['#define ATTR_A          (HELLO +1L)     /*FSDSDF*/',
         '#define ATTR_B          (HELLO +2L)     /*FSFSSF*/']

r = re.compile(r'#define (\w*)\s*(\(.*\))')

for line in input:
    m = r.match(line)
    print '%s = %s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

**Output:**

```
ATTR_A = (HELLO +1L)
ATTR_B = (HELLO +2L)
```